# Spec dummy not recognizing module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, require

I have a set up where I want to factor out code that is used both within, and outside of an engine into a module. However when running engine `spec` dummy tests, the dummy fails to find the module in my main app's lib folder (I think it is scoped to the directory of the engine) and rake aborts.

Here's the general set up:

This will lie in the main app's lib folder (`my_module.rb`):

```
module MyModule
   def module_function
   end
end
```

This will lie in the main app's model directory:

```
require 'my_module'
class myModel
  include MyModule
  module_function()
end
```

This will lie in the engine:

```
require 'my_module' 
class MyEngineModel
  include myModule
  module_function() 
end
```

However on the rake setup for dummy, it craps out giving me a `load error` for the engine spec:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- my_module
```

Answer (score 0):

The Engine is loaded before the main application. So, if your module is to be used in both the engine and the app, I would suggest you put it in the Engine's `lib/` folder as opposed to the application's lib folder.

You might find more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#hooking-into-an-application)